# pandas- get_dummies() result in memory error

Tags: python, memory, pandas, scikit-learn, dataframe

This might be a stupid question....I am using pd.get_dummies() to create new binary features (about 5000) from a column in a dataframe, however, it resulted in memory error. I think probably 5000 is too big? My laptop has 8G memory. Is there any way to solve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: You nailed it.  If you're running out of memory on get_dummies, you're going to have a hard time fitting a model.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I saw there are some people claimed they are using thousands of features to fit a model. Are they using super machine?

Comment: You can easily install pandas / scikit learn on an AWS instance with > 200 GB Ram for very little cost.  You also probably don't need to start with 5000 features, but that all depends on the model / problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get\_dummies python memory error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31321892/get-dummies-python-memory-error)