# get_dummies() throws Memory Error

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I am trying the create a matrix of data from 7 csv to find out common words among the files.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('A.csv', sep=";", index_col=None, header=None)
df2 = pd.read_csv('B.csv', sep=";", index_col=None, header=None)
df3 = pd.read_csv('C.csv', sep=";", index_col=None, header=None)
df4 = pd.read_csv('D.csv', sep=";", index_col=None, header=None)
df5 = pd.read_csv('E.csv', sep=";", index_col=None, header=None)
df6 = pd.read_csv('F.csv', sep=";", index_col=None, header=None)
df7 = pd.read_csv('G.csv', sep=";", index_col=None, header=None)

df = pd.concat([df1,df2,df3,df4,df5,df6,df7], keys=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G'])
df.reset_index(1, drop=True, inplace=True)

res = df.stack().reset_index(1, drop=True)
val = res.str.get_dummies().groupby(level=0).sum().T

val.to_csv('result.csv')
```

This code works perfectly if I use 2-3 csv but when I use all 7 csv the words list goes above 60000 and the get_dummies() throws Memory Error, my system gets hanged and I need to restart the system. Is there some way to resolve this issue.

Comment: Check the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31321892/get-dummies-python-memory-error) Seems to work for a number of people