# how to resolve memory error caused by Get_dummies

Tags: python, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I am using Python and I have dataset that has around 1 million records and around 50 column

some of these columns has different types (such as IssueCode column can have 7000 different codes, another column SolutionCode can have 1000 codes)

I am trying to build a predictive model.

therefore I have to convert data using get_dummies

but this has been causing this error **Memory Error**

> File
>   "C:\Users\am\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\reshape.py",
>   line 963, in _get_dummies_1d
>       dummy_mat = np.eye(number_of_cols, dtype=dtype).take(codes, axis=0)
>
> MemoryError

I tried another solution by keeping columns without one-hot-encoding

now I get this error when try to build the model

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'ABC'

I checked this solution

[get_dummies python memory error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31321892/get-dummies-python-memory-error)

I converted all columns to int8 but still the same error

```
df = pd.concat([df.drop('IssueCode', 1), pd.get_dummies(df['IssueCode'],prefix = 'IssueCode_').astype(np.int8)], axis=1)
df = pd.concat([df.drop('SolutionCode', 1), pd.get_dummies(df['SolutionCode'],prefix = 'SolutionCode_').astype(np.int8)], axis=1)
df = pd.concat([df.drop('Col1', 1), pd.get_dummies(df['Col1'],prefix = 'Col1_').astype(np.int8)], axis=1)
df = pd.concat([df.drop('Col2', 1), pd.get_dummies(df['Col2'],prefix = 'Col2_').astype(np.int8)], axis=1)
df = pd.concat([df.drop('Col3', 1), pd.get_dummies(df['Col3'],prefix = 'Col3_').astype(np.int8)], axis=1)
```

I cannot get_dummies due to memory error and I cannot Not to get_dummies due to string to float Error

How to solve this

here is my code

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_predict
import pymssql
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
import datetime
import random
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor


pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 5000)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 5000)
pd.set_option('display.width', 10000)


TaskTime = 900
RunTime = 120
sFolder = "/mnt/c/temp/"

def Lead0(value): 
        return "0" + str(value) if value < 10 else str(value)

dNow = datetime.datetime.now()
sNow = Lead0(dNow.year) + Lead0(dNow.month) + Lead0(dNow.day) + Lead0(dNow.hour) + Lead0(dNow.minute) + Lead0(dNow.second) 

print(sNow)

conn = pymssql.connect(server="MyServer", database="MyDB", port="1433", user="***", password="*****")
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT   *  FROM MyTable where MyDate between '1 jul 2018' and '30 jun 2019'", conn)
conn.close()


#df = pd.get_dummies(df)
#When I uncomment this I get Memory Error


mdl = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 500) 

y_pred = cross_val_predict(mdl, X, y, cv=5)
#This is causing error String to float
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing you may want to do is to specify appropriate data types for data frame columns to reduce the memory usage of the loaded dataframe (cf. https://www.dataquest.io/blog/pandas-big-data/).

As for one-hot encoding, one direct solution of the memory issue is to use sparse data types rather than regular data types (see [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/sparse.html) for more details). This can be achieved by something like this:

```
df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=["IssueCode", "SolutionCode", "Col1", "Col2", "Col3"], 
                    sparse=True, axis=1)
```

I am not sure whether `pandas`' sparse representation works well with `sklearn` though. If it does not work, you could try using `sklearn`'s [OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html), which also offers sparse representation by default.

There are also other encoding techniques of categorical features that reduces dimensions (as well as the memory usage) but requires more work, e.g. merging values of categorical features into larger groups.